# Regular Expression to extract text containing pipe charcters

Tags: java, regex

I have a string and required an regular expression to extract the substring from a string.

Example: `this is a|b|c|d whatever e|f|g|h`
Result: `a|b|c|d, e|f|g|h`

However based on the Java code that I wrote, it is producing the results as follows:

```
Pattern ptyy = Pattern.compile("\\|*.+? ");
Matcher matcher_values = ptyy.matcher("this is a|b|c|d whatever e|f|g|h");
while (matcher_values.find()) {
    String line = matcher_values.group(0);
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

**Result**

```
this 
is 
a|b|c|d 
whatever
```

The result is not what I have hoped for. Any advice?

Comment: Try [`/[^\s|]+(?:\|[^\s|])+/g`](https://regex101.com/r/aL9bL4/1)

Comment: Do you only want single letters? Or should `foo|bar|baz|qux` match? Also, is it always exactly 4 terms, or should `a|b|c` match?

Comment: I also want to match foo|bar|baz|qux, foo2|ba2r|baz|qux5  as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `\|*.+?`  pattern matches 0 or more pipes, then 1 or more any chars other than a newline up to the first space. Thus, it matches almost all non-whitespace chunks in a string.

If `a`, `b` and `c` are just placeholders and there can be any non-whitespace chars, I'd suggest:

```
[^\s|]+(?:\|[^\s|])+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/aL9bL4/1)

**Details**:

- `[^\s|]+`  - 1 or more chars other than whitespace and `|`
- `(?:\|[^\s|])+` - 1 or more sequences of:

  - `\|` -  a literal `|`
  - `[^\s|]` - 1 or more chars other than whitespace and `|`

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/91YmuV):

```
Pattern ptyy = Pattern.compile("[^\\s|]+(?:\\|[^\\s|])+");
Matcher matcher_values = ptyy.matcher("this is a|b|c|d whatever e|f|g|h");
while (matcher_values.find()) {
    String line = matcher_values.group(0);
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this regex is enough `(.\|)+.`

see the [example](https://regex101.com/r/sY0gY6/1)

**`(.\|)`** this find all the `a|b|...|` and last **`.`** find the last char of the sub-string.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your advice, i managed to come up with my own regular expression that can address different combination of the pipe expression.

```
Pattern ptyy = Pattern.compile("[^\\s|]+(?:\\|[^\\s|])+");
Matcher matcher_values = ptyy.matcher("this is a|b|c|d whater e|f|g|h and Az|09|23|A3 and 22|1212|12121|55555");
while (matcher_values.find()) {
    String line = matcher_values.group(0);
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

This will enable me to get the result

```
a|b|c|d
e|f|g|h
Az|09|23|A
22|1212|12121|5
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Sorry, but it is *exactly* the regex **I** suggested in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38716040/3832970). If it works for you, there is no point posting duplicate solutions. Please consider deleting this post and accepting my answer.